How to Properly Center Two Groups of PCBs with Test and Impedance Coupons in HTML Canvas?
I'm working on a PCB panel visualization in an HTML5 canvas where I need to place two groups of PCBs for a given panel area. Each group has:
4 test coupons (2 vertical, 2 horizontal) surrounding the PCBs.
A dynamic number of impedance coupons, placed based on a given number (e.g., numImpedance = 1 should place 1 on the left; numImpedance = 3 should place 1 on the left, 1 on the top, and 1 on the right).
What I'm Looking For:
I need help to:
Correctly place the vertically aligned test coupons so they don't overlap the midline.
Ensure there's adequate space for the impedance coupons and they are placed without overlapping.
Ensure both groups are centered and properly aligned within the panel area.
Any suggestions or improvements on the logic or approach would be greatly appreciated!
Here's my approach:
Calculate the number of PCBs to draw after subtracting space for test coupons and impedance coupons.
Center the PCB area within the available space.
Surround it with test coupons.
Surround it with the given number of impedance coupons.


const canvas = document.getElementById('pcbCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 406;
canvas.height = 533;

const x_border = 406;
const y_border = 533;

const top_mn = 17;
const bot_mn = 17;
const left_mn = 17;
const right_mn = 17;

const routerGap = 1.6;

// Test coupon dimensions
const couponWidth = 35.0; // Width in mm
const couponHeight = 195.0; // Height in mm

function drawPCBs2withImpedance(orientation) {
  if (orientation === "horizontal") {
    pcbWidth = 93;
    pcbHeight = 100;
  } else {
    pcbWidth = 100;
    pcbHeight = 85;
  }

  // Clear the canvas and set the background
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#505050";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, x_border, y_border);

  // Calculate active area dimensions
  const activeWidth = x_border - left_mn - right_mn;
  const activeHeight = y_border - top_mn - bot_mn; // Split height into two halves

  ctx.fillStyle = "Gold";
  ctx.fillRect(left_mn, top_mn, activeWidth, activeHeight);

  var mid_active_panel_len = activeHeight / 2.0;

  var mid_line_len = y_border / 2.0;
  mid_active_panel_len = mid_active_panel_len;
  console.log(activeHeight, y_border, mid_active_panel_len, mid_line_len)

  var mid_active_panel_bre = activeWidth / 2.0;
  var half_mid = mid_active_panel_bre / 2.0
  mid_active_panel_bre = mid_active_panel_bre + left_mn + routerGap;

  horz_end = x_border - right_mn;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(left_mn, mid_line_len);
  ctx.lineTo(horz_end, mid_line_len);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "Crimson";
  ctx.stroke();
  var numImpCoupons = 2;
  var impCouponWidth = 25;
  var impCouponHeight = 200;

  var impCoupns = calculateImpedanceCoupons(numImpCoupons);
  console.log(impCoupns)
  // Assuming impCoupns contains the number of coupons on each side
  const impCouponSpaceLeft = impCoupns.left * (impCouponWidth + routerGap);
  const impCouponSpaceRight = impCoupns.right * (impCouponWidth + routerGap);
  const impCouponSpaceTop = impCoupns.top * (impCouponWidth + routerGap);
  const impCouponSpaceBottom = impCoupns.bottom * (impCouponWidth + routerGap);

  console.log("sss", impCouponSpaceTop + impCouponSpaceBottom)

  // Total available width and height after placing impedance coupons
  const availableWidth = x_border - impCouponSpaceLeft - impCouponSpaceRight - left_mn - right_mn - 2 * (couponWidth + routerGap);
  // const availableHeight1 = mid_line_len - impCouponSpaceTop - impCouponSpaceBottom - 2 * (couponWidth + routerGap);
  const availableHeight1 = (mid_line_len - top_mn) - impCouponSpaceTop - impCouponSpaceBottom - 2 * (couponWidth + routerGap);

  console.log("availableHeight", mid_line_len, availableHeight1)

  // Calculate number of PCBs that can fit in the remaining area
  const numPcbsX1 = Math.floor(availableWidth / (pcbWidth + routerGap));
  const numPcbsY1 = Math.floor(availableHeight1 / (pcbHeight + routerGap));

  // Calculate the PCB area dimensions
  const pcbAreaWidth1 = numPcbsX1 * (pcbWidth + routerGap) - routerGap;
  const pcbAreaHeight1 = numPcbsY1 * (pcbHeight + routerGap) - routerGap;

  // Center the PCB area within the available space
  const pcbAreaX1 = (availableWidth - pcbAreaWidth1) / 2 + impCouponSpaceLeft + couponWidth + routerGap + left_mn;
  const pcbAreaY1 = (availableHeight1 - pcbAreaHeight1) / 2 + impCouponSpaceTop + impCouponSpaceBottom + couponWidth;
  // const pcbAreaY2 = mid_line_len + (availableHeight1 - pcbAreaHeight1) / 2 + impCouponSpaceTop + impCouponSpaceBottom + couponWidth + routerGap ;
  const pcbAreaY2 = mid_line_len + (availableHeight1 - pcbAreaHeight1) / 2 + impCouponSpaceTop + impCouponSpaceBottom + couponWidth + routerGap;
  ctx.fillStyle = "#00a2ed";

  console.log(numPcbsX1, numPcbsY1)
  for (let y = 0; y < numPcbsY1; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < numPcbsX1; x++) {
      const xPos = pcbAreaX1 + x * (pcbWidth + routerGap);
      const yPos = pcbAreaY1 + y * (pcbHeight + routerGap);
      ctx.fillRect(xPos, yPos, pcbWidth, pcbHeight);
    }
  }

  for (let y = 0; y < numPcbsY1; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < numPcbsX1; x++) {
      const xPos = pcbAreaX1 + x * (pcbWidth + routerGap);
      const yPos = pcbAreaY2 + y * (pcbHeight + routerGap);
      ctx.fillRect(xPos, yPos, pcbWidth, pcbHeight);
    }
  }
  ctx.fillStyle = "DarkOrange";
  // top coupon
  const topCouponX1 = pcbAreaX1;
  const topCouponY1 = pcbAreaY1 - couponWidth - routerGap;
  ctx.fillRect(topCouponX1, topCouponY1, couponHeight, couponWidth);

  //bottom coupon
  const bottomCouponX1 = pcbAreaX1 + pcbAreaWidth1 - couponHeight
  const bottomCouponY1 = pcbAreaY1 + pcbAreaHeight1 + routerGap
  ctx.fillRect(bottomCouponX1, bottomCouponY1, couponHeight, couponWidth);
  ctx.fillStyle = "Green";
  //Right Coupon
  const rightCouponX1 = pcbAreaX1 + pcbAreaWidth1 + routerGap;
  const rightCouponY1 = pcbAreaY1 - couponWidth - routerGap;



  //left coupon
  const leftCouponX1 = pcbAreaX1 - couponWidth - routerGap;
  const leftCouponY1 = pcbAreaY1 - couponWidth - routerGap


  ctx.fillStyle = "DarkOrange";
  // top coupon
  const topCouponX2 = pcbAreaX1;
  const topCouponY2 = pcbAreaY2 - couponWidth - routerGap;
  ctx.fillRect(topCouponX2, topCouponY2, couponHeight, couponWidth);

  //bottom coupon
  const bottomCouponX2 = pcbAreaX1 + pcbAreaWidth1 - couponHeight
  const bottomCouponY2 = pcbAreaY2 + pcbAreaHeight1 + routerGap
  ctx.fillRect(bottomCouponX2, bottomCouponY2, couponHeight, couponWidth);
  ctx.fillStyle = "Green";
  //left coupon
  const leftCouponX2 = pcbAreaX1 - couponWidth - routerGap;
  const leftCouponY2 = pcbAreaY2 - couponWidth - routerGap


  //Right Coupon
  const rightCouponX2 = pcbAreaX1 + pcbAreaWidth1 + routerGap;
  const rightCouponY2 = pcbAreaY2 - couponWidth - routerGap;


  if (pcbAreaWidth1 > couponHeight) {
    //Right Coupon
    ctx.fillRect(rightCouponX1, rightCouponY1, couponWidth, couponHeight);
    ctx.fillRect(rightCouponX2, rightCouponY2, couponWidth, couponHeight);

    ctx.fillRect(leftCouponX1, leftCouponY1, couponWidth, couponHeight);
    ctx.fillRect(leftCouponX2, leftCouponY2, couponWidth, couponHeight);

  } else {

    var adjustSpace = couponHeight - pcbAreaWidth1;
    console.log(pcbAreaWidth1, couponHeight, leftCouponX1, adjustSpace)
    ctx.fillRect(rightCouponX1 + adjustSpace, rightCouponY1, couponWidth, couponHeight);
    ctx.fillRect(rightCouponX2 + adjustSpace, rightCouponY2, couponWidth, couponHeight);

    ctx.fillRect(leftCouponX1 - adjustSpace, leftCouponY1, couponWidth, couponHeight);
    ctx.fillRect(leftCouponX2 - adjustSpace, leftCouponY2, couponWidth, couponHeight);
  }

  // Update active and non-utilized dimensions
  document.getElementById("act-length").innerHTML = "Active Breadth X Length : " + parseInt(activeWidth) + " X " + parseInt(activeHeight * 2);
  document.getElementById("non-act-length").innerHTML = "Non Utilized Breadth X Length : " + parseInt(x_border - activeWidth) + " X " + parseInt(y_border - (activeHeight * 2));
}



document.querySelectorAll('input[name="orientation"]').forEach(radio => {
  radio.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    drawPCBs2withImpedance(event.target.value);
  });
});

drawPCBs2withImpedance('horizontal');



function calculateImpedanceCoupons(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    console.log("The number of coupons must be at least 1.");
    var abc2 = {
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      xAxis: 0,
      yAxis: 0
    }
    return abc2;
  }

  let left = 0,
    top = 0,
    right = 0,
    bottom = 0,
    xAxis = 0,
    yAxis = 0;

  if (n === 1) {
    left = 1;
  } else if (n === 2) {
    left = 1;
    top = 1;
  } else if (n === 3) {
    left = 1;
    top = 1;
    right = 1;
  } else {
    left = 1;
    top = 1;
    right = 1;
    bottom = 1;

    // Distribute the remaining coupons
    let remainingCoupons = n - 4;
    if (remainingCoupons > 0) {
      let additionalCouponsPerSide = Math.floor(remainingCoupons / 4);
      let extraCoupons = remainingCoupons % 4;

      left += additionalCouponsPerSide + (extraCoupons > 0 ? 1 : 0);
      top += additionalCouponsPerSide + (extraCoupons > 1 ? 1 : 0);
      right += additionalCouponsPerSide + (extraCoupons > 2 ? 1 : 0);
      bottom += additionalCouponsPerSide;
    }
  }

  var abc = {
    left: left,
    top: top,
    right: right,
    bottom: bottom,
    xAxis: left + right,
    yAxis: top + bottom
  }

  return abc;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>PCB Panel Visualization</title>
  <style>
    body {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    canvas {
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    
    .controls {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="controls">
    <label><input type="radio" name="orientation" value="horizontal" checked> Horizontal</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="orientation" value="vertical"> Vertical</label>

    <div id="act-length"></div>
    <div id="non-act-length"></div>
  </div>
  <canvas id="pcbCanvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>



Problem:
The vertically placed coupons are overlapping on the midline, which shouldn't happen.
There is often no space for the impedance coupons due to the placement of other elements.
I want both groups to be centered and non-overlapping, but my current logic isn't achieving this.
